# Why quantum gravity can't be described by spin-1 bosons?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles

As the title suggests, why quantum gravity can't be described by spin-1 gravitons?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/680513/

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230/2451 and links therein.